# developer.ubuntu.com - only for mobile apps now?

Tags: application-development

I tried to look there for some guides for desktop application development, as I had done before, but found none! Is it only a temporary problem because of Ubuntu going mobile, or I should look someplace else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ubuntu gonna use same apps for phone,tablet and desktop . So they deprecated desktop specific tools like quickly pyGTK etc. If you want to write apps for future ubuntu releases , the only officially recommended way is Ubuntu SDK .

Comment: Really? You sure? No more Quickly? That is very strange...

Comment: Yes, now quickly is not a recommended tool. It will available in the repository, but not officially recommended

Comment: That is a pity, quickly is a great tool. So, no more official information about it... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question, the site is surely not only for mobile apps. There is a search field there that can help you: http://developer.ubuntu.com/?s=guide+desktop+application.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! So it seems, it just temporarily lacks links to all that stuff, but has it there somewhere.